# Test run cron entry

Tags: linux, unix, cron

I added a cron job recently, but made a mistake in the path while giving the command and hence, the job never succeeded. Is there some way to test the cron changes we have done?

Please note that I had indeed copied and pasted the command from my command line and it was just an stray keypress that caused this.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This question has also been asked on [serverfault and has garnered a couple additional answers](https://serverfault.com/questions/85893/running-a-cron-job-manually-and-immediately)

The following is a paraphrased version of [Marco's solution](https://serverfault.com/a/541368):
(Not sure if best etiquette is not providing a link only answer or not copying someone else's solution)

Create a environment file with a temporary cron entry

```
* * * * *  /usr/bin/env > /home/username/cron-env
```

Then create a shell script called `run-as-cron` which executes the command using that environment.

```
#!/bin/sh

. "$1"
exec /usr/bin/env -i "$SHELL" -c ". $1; $2"
```

Give it execute permission

```
chmod +x run-as-cron
```

and then it is then used like this:

```
./run-as-cron <cron-environment> <command>
```

e.g.

```
./run-as-cron /home/username/cron-env 'echo $PATH'
```

Comment: If this does not work for you, see Fuujuh's answer for a modification.  He says that run-as-cron needs "setsid" and "set -a" to work.

Comment: Thanks for good explanation

Comment: I have to add that /bin/env > filename does not work so well for me. This is because if I have a variable declared as `test="hello world"` then in the environment file, this will be saved as `test=hello world` without quotes. So I have had better success with `export -p > /tmp/env`.

Answer (score 69):

When I want to test my cron jobs I usually set the interval very low and monitor the logs closely. When I am convinced the entry is correct, I set the interval back to a sane value.

For example, run job every two minutes:

`*/2 * * * *     echo "Hello World"`

And the I run `tail -f` on my log file (`/var/log/syslog`on debian).

Comment: That's what I do as well, except with one minute... but I wish there were a way to just ask crontab to run it with a command, so that one wouldn't have to always wait for up to a minute until crontab executes the command, just to see if it's going to run.

Comment: The closest you'll get is by running `/bin/sh`. Then again, you shouldn't run complex commands directly from cron. Use an external script instead!

Comment: Exactly, so when the /bin/sh run works but not the cron job, it gets quite frustrating debugging it, even if it's just the waiting of 40-50 seconds to see if it works next time.

Comment: Small addendum for special cases: if you are running a command that rarely generates output (like "git fetch") and it is a user cron job, so you don't have access to /var/log/syslog, you can do something like this to ensure you get output you can inspect: `date >> git.log && git --git-dir=~/foo fetch >> git.log 2>&1`

Comment: @Teekin 40-50 seconds feels like eons of time for a programmer... :)

Comment: @PerLundberg: Yes, and easily expands. If you need to try 10 different things to fix something, then it takes at least 10 minutes instead of maybe 1. It's the equivalent of a compilation process taking an entire minute for every minimal change in code. It would be unbearable.

Comment: `*/2  * * * *`  learned something there!

Answer (score 10):

Joshua's answer does not work for me. Two problems:

- Variables in `cron-env` file are not exported (`set -a` needed).
- Script is still tied to current tty (`setsid` needed).

The script `run-as-cron` should be

```
#!/bin/sh

. "$1"
exec setsid /usr/bin/env -i "$SHELL" -c "set -a; . $1; $2" </dev/null
```

Not enough rep' to fix his answer or add a comment...

Answer (score -1):

Use command `crontab -e`.

This will open an editor and all you got to do here is:

```
* * * * * /somepath/urscript.sh
```

make sure you have the appropriate spaces between dates and the path of the script

After the execution , you can check in the `/var/spool/mail<user>` there will a complete trail of the script execution or errors.
For testing there is no way .. but in case ur sh urscript.sh works then cron tab will have no problem as it is exactly same thing what u do manually.